# Parse an xml file with python

Tags: python, xml

Hese is the file the file.xml file [xml file link](http://apprendre-python.com/page-xml-python-xpath)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user data-id="101">
        <nom>Zorro</nom>
        <metier>Danseur</metier>
    </user>
    <user data-id="102">
        <nom>Hulk</nom>
        <metier>Footballeur</metier>
    </user>
    <user data-id="103">
        <nom>Zidane</nom>
        <metier>Star</metier>
    </user>
    <user data-id="104">
        <nom>Beans</nom>
        <metier>Epicier</metier>
    </user>
    <user data-id="105">
        <nom>Batman</nom>
        <metier>Veterinaire</metier>
    </user>
    <user data-id="106">
        <nom>Spiderman</nom>
        <metier>Veterinaire</metier>
    </user>
</users>
```

for example: I want to show the metier for each user

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("file.xml")
for metier in tree.xpath("/users/user/metier"):
    print(metier.text)
```

The script is run without problem but it shows nothing. It seems like `tree.xpath("/users/user/metier")` is empty!!

Comment: `tree` searches relative to the root-element. Use `tree.xpath("user/metier")`.

Comment: @Daniel thanks! I will put the answer if you let me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tree.xpath` searches relative to the root-element `<users>`. So `users` must not be part of the path:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("file.xml")
for metier in tree.xpath("user/metier"):
    print(metier.text)
```